# Cordova Application will work on PhoneGap Build?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I have created a Cordova based application and uploaded Project.zip file into build.phonegap.com and created a build for iOS and Android, the HTML UI is working fine. but I not able to access the Camera API which I have used in the project.

Cordova Projects are will work on PhoneGap Build?. is there any restrictions.

Comment: You have to use a different `config.xml`for PGBuild. This includes entries for which plugins your app requires.

Comment: refer this http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/introduction_getting_started.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Build

Comment: @DawsonLoudon if i modified config.xml it will work for Cordova Project not phonegap project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have several issues :

- the config.xml created using cordova cli uses a DTD not compatible with phonegap build specific settings
- to add a plugin in a phonegap build project you have to reference it in config.xml.
- only plugins that have been submited to Phonegap Build team can be used in Build projects

So

1. modify the `<widget>` definition in config.xml to use `xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"` instead of `xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"`
2. add a `<gap:plugin>` line for each plugin you need to add to your project
3. refer to https://build.phonegap.com/plugins for the list of available plugins for Build

Config.xml modified for PG Build is still compatible with Cordova CLI.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a config.xml file to your app, and in that you need to add the Camera Plugin (and any other Plugin APIs you want).

[Here's the docs](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_plugins.md.html#Plugins), and [here is an example app](https://github.com/wildabeast/PhonegapBuildTester).

Also it sounds like you may have zipped up your entire project and uploaded it to Phonegap Build -- you should only upload your `www` directory.